# My Localhost:4200 is not showing my angular project

Tags: angular, localhost, liveserver

My localhost:4200 is not showing anything of my project, it was showing the project before. But after the latest changes in generating a new component and working on it, it was blank when I tried.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngdUI.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0vFt.jpg)

Comment: what the error showing in console(F12) ?

Comment: As per the screenshot, your application has loaded but has encountered a runtime error. Check the console errors. 
My guess: Your component wouldn't have been registered in any module

Comment: it's looks like your index.html has no the adecuate "tag" (check your main.module.ts and check what is the boostrapped component)

Answer (score 1):

1. Enable auto save or save and run again
2. Open dev tools(Right click >> inspect  >> console tab) and check the error.

Answer (score 0):

Is Autosave on? Try enabling it and refreshing your project. Else press ctrl+c and terminate the earlier command and run it again.